# How can I adjust the position of multiple \vdots after multiple \begin{cases}?

Tags: vertical-alignment, amsmath, article, cases, multline

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}

%=====

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\\
%
\text{Text}
\begin{cases}
AAA\\ 
AAA
\end{cases}\\
%
\text{Text}
\begin{cases}
AAA\\ 
AAA
\end{cases}\\
%
\text{Text}
\begin{cases}
AAA\\ 
AAA
\end{cases}\\
%
\vdots\vdots\vdots\vdots\\
%
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

I would like to be able to properly align the multiple `\vdots`. I think it would be fine if I could manually adjust the position of the multiple `\vdots`.

The first `\vdots` should be aligned with "Text". As regards the rest of the `\vdots`, each should be aligned with one letter A.

How can I do this?

Comment: It's not clear why you're using `multline`. What alignment do you have in mind?

Comment: @egreg The first `\vdots` should be aligned with "Text". As regards the rest of the `\vdots`, each should be aligned with one letter A.

Comment: @egreg It would be fine if I could adjust the horizontal position (with cm or pt) of each `\vdots`.

Comment: OK, but I don't think your display will really be like that. Aligning under each `A` is not difficult, but the real problem will be different, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TeX engines pdfTeX, LuaTeX, and XeTeX do support the feature `\pdfsavepos` that can be used to record the current position (which is known later at shipout time) to the `.aux` file. The positions can then be used in the next LaTeX run.
For example, package `zref-savepos` provides an interface to this feature.

The middle of the elements are get by a trick, the element is made a math operator, then a subscript goes into the middle. Thus the subscript is used
to record the horizontal position (`\zsaveposx`). In case of `A`, the expression is put into `\smash` to not disturb the normal typesetting, the size of brace, by an invisible height or especially depth.

Then at the target line, a box of zero width is used to get a fixed position.
The current horizontal position is recorded and then the difference of the horizontal positions is used to set the vertical dots.

Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{zsaveposx}{% older zref
  \let\zsaveposx\zsavepos
  \let\zsaveposy\zsavepos
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\\
%
\text{Text}
\begin{cases}
AAA\\ 
AAA
\end{cases}\\
%
\text{Text}
\begin{cases}
AAA\\ 
AAA
\end{cases}\\
%
\mathop{\text{Text}}_{\zsaveposx{Text}}
\begin{cases}
AAA\\
\def\Apos#1{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \smash{$\mathop{\hphantom{A}}\limits_{\zsaveposx{A#1}}$}%
  }%
  A%
}
\Apos1 \Apos2 \Apos3
\end{cases}\\
\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \zsaveposx{vdots0}%
  \kern-\zposx{vdots0}sp%
  \def\putdots#1{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \kern\zposx{#1}sp%
      \makebox[0pt][c]{%
        $\vdots$%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \putdots{Text}%
  \putdots{A1}%
  \putdots{A2}%
  \putdots{A3}%
}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Result after *two* LaTeX runs:

> [image: Result]

### Example with BCD

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts, amsthm, amsmath, amssymb}

\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\makeatletter
\@ifundefined{zsaveposx}{% older zref
  \let\zsaveposx\zsavepos
  \let\zsaveposy\zsavepos
}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
\\
%
\text{Text}
\begin{cases}
AAA\\ 
AAA
\end{cases}\\
%
\text{Text}
\begin{cases}
AAA\\ 
AAA
\end{cases}\\
%
\mathop{\text{Text}}_{\zsaveposx{Text}}
\begin{cases}
AAA\\
\def\Apos#1#2{%
  \makebox[0pt][l]{%
    \smash{$\mathop{\hphantom{#1}}\limits_{\zsaveposx{A#2}}$}%
  }%
  #1%
}
\Apos B1 \Apos C2 \Apos D3
\end{cases}\\
\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \zsaveposx{vdots0}%
  \kern-\zposx{vdots0}sp%
  \def\putdots#1{%
    \makebox[0pt][l]{%
      \kern\zposx{#1}sp%
      \makebox[0pt][c]{%
        $\vdots$%
      }%
    }%
  }%
  \putdots{Text}%
  \putdots{A1}%
  \putdots{A2}%
  \putdots{A3}%
}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result BCD]

### Next example

From the [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/177064/how-can-i-adjust-the-position-of-multiple-vdots-after-multiple-begincases/177067?noredirect=1#comment410036_177067):

> what about if on the last line I want to have a two-digit number (on
>   the 1st column), a mathematical symbol (on the 2nd column) and another
>   two digit-number (on the 3rd column)?

Replace the line of the previous example

```
\Apos B1 \Apos C2 \Apos D3
```

with

```
\Apos{12}{1} \mathbin{\Apos{+}{2}} \Apos{34}{3}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This is exactly what I want! But for some reason I'm getting an error message (undefined control sequence).

Comment: @UserX: The undefined control sequence is at the end of the line in the error message. If it is `\zsaveposx`, then just use `\zsavepos`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What about if I want to have something different on the last line, for example BCD?

Comment: @UserX: Example with BCD added. Helper macro with two arguments, the symbol and a number. The label names remain `A1` to `A3`.

Comment: One more question: what about if on the last line I want to have a two-digit number (on the 1st column), a mathematical symbol (on the 2nd column) and another two digit-number (on the 3rd column)?